# Monitoring a single file

Tags: python, watchdog

I need to monitor (using [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/index.html)) a single file, not a whole directory.

What is the best way to avoid monitoring a whole directory?
I suppose [this](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/_modules/watchdog/events.html#PatternMatchingEventHandler)

```
class watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns=None, ignore_patterns=None, ignore_directories=False, case_sensitive=False)[source]
```

could be helpful, but how to define an appropriate pattern for my file (*C:/dir1/dir2/file.txt)*?

Comment: Sorry for being off topic, but I can't resist my curiosity. Why would someone call themselves Tom Cruise? :)

Comment: `s/dictionary/directory/g` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to watch a file path like `C:/dict1/dict2/file.txt`, I think that's your pattern right there.  There are no wildcards in, so it should be usable as-is.

As an aside, if Watchdog is giving you trouble, you could also consider Pyinotify: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

Comment: Yes, but `C:/dict1/dict2/file.txt` as a pattern doesn't work ... and pyinotify works only on Linux.

Comment: @TomCruise You may have to put it in a list, e.g. `PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns=['C:/dict1/dict2/file.txt'], ...)`

Comment: YES! It has to be a list! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The way to provide patterns for `PatternMatchingEventHandler` is

```
 from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

 class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
     patterns = ["*.xml", "*.log", "*/test.txt"] # */test.txt to watch that specifi file
```

Comment: Python watchdog still watches the whole directory under the hood in Linux and generates inotify events internally, the handlers just filter off what you don't want to deal with. Watchdog is not the solution for this. Just activate debug logging for your project and you'll see.

Comment: hi @ravi404 and @Rene, what do i put in `ignore_patterns`, if i want to ignore every file format but ".csv" (my `patterns="*.csv"`)?